# Exclude object if object is private

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

How can I remove an object from a queryset if that object has a boolean field set to true? I need to remove it from the queryset as I am later serializing it with DRF.

```
qs = Post.objects.all()

for post in qs:
    if post.private == True and post.user.pk != request.user.pk:
        post.remove()
```

I cannot use `exclude()` as I need the condition to check wherever the owner of the object (user) is the authenticated one and if the object is set to private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pulling all posts, then removing private ones that do not belong to the user, pull all public posts and add private posts that the user can see.

```
from django.db.models import Q

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # Return public (private=False), and private posts of the user
    visible_posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(private=False) |
                                        Q(private=True, user=request.user))
else:
    # Only return public posts
    visible_posts = Post.objects.filter(private=False)
```

If you don't have an authenticated user, just

The `Q` allows you form more complex queries, if you're not familiar, you can read above query as "public posts or private posts belonging to the user"

Comment: This throws an exception on AnonymousUser

Comment: If user anonymous just go with public posts only, `Post.objects.filter(private=False)`